# Interpolation of user input strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-interpolation

I can't strongly formulate what I need now, but the idea is this:

User inputs some string that looks like a template

```
'Welcome to #{country}!' # or 'Welcome to %%country%%!', it's not essential
```

Is there some gem (or may be standard tool like Erb), that could do 2 things:

1. Validate given string (i.e. if I allow to pass only `country` as parameter, strings with another parameters will not be valid)
2. Interpolate given string with passed parameters (i.e. `some_method('Welcome to #{country}!', country: 'Russia')) # => 'Welcome to Russia!'`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
"Welcome to %{country}!" % {country: "Russia"}
# => "Welcome to Russia!"

"Welcome to %{country}!" % {person: "John"}
# => KeyError: key{country} not found
```

Comment: I have never seen such code :). interesting one. what that `%` is called?